# How can I improve my code for text file with hex for clarity and simplicity?

Tags: binary, mips

I am taking in a text file with hex like this

the point of the program is to convert these values to mips instructions. Is there a better way to rewrite or improve my code? I am fairly new to c# and would like to see if I can improve this program.

Comment: I would recommend you to correctly indent your code as first step. The `case 0x02:` has the same indent level as `case 0x0c:`. But the `case 0x02:` is in another `switch`. This is confusing when you do not read the code detailed and can cause problems understanding and analysing the code.

Comment: You shall define more purpose from this code, what is you intention, just to print on the screen / console as you have done or you want to get the output and supply it to another method. Currently if its just printing then your code is doing as expected, you may introduce few superficial things, but essence will remain same

Comment: The purpose of this code is to make a mips translator. basically simulating a cpu where it takes in hex values and translates them to actual mips instructions

Answer (score 1):

Return an [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield)

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetCode(IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
   foreach (var line in Lines)
   {
      var binary = Convert.ToUInt32(line, 16);
      var opCode = binary >> 26;
      var funCode = binary & 0x3f;
      var rs = (binary >> 21) & 31;
      var rt = (binary >> 16) & 31;
      var rd = (binary >> 11) & 31;
      int nImm = (short)(binary & 0xffff);
      var jImm = (binary & 0x03ffffff) << 2;

      switch (opCode)
      {
         case 0x00:
            switch (funCode)
            {
               case 0x0c: yield return "syscall"; break;
               case 0x20: yield return $"add\t{_reg[rd]}, {_reg[rs]}, {_reg[rt]}";  break;
            } break;
         case 0x02: yield return $"j\t0x00{jImm:x04}";  break;
         case 0x04: yield return $"beq\t{_reg[rs]}, {_reg[rt]}, 0x{nImm:x04}"; break;
         case 0x08: yield return $"addi\t{_reg[rt]}, {_reg[rs]}, {nImm}"; break;
         case 0x0d: yield return $"ori\t{_reg[rt]}, {_reg[rs]}, 0x{nImm:x04}"; break;
         case 0x0f: yield return $"lui\t{_reg[rt]}, 0x{nImm:x04}"; break;
         case 0x23: yield return $"lw\t{_reg[rt]}, {nImm}({_reg[rs]})"; break;
         case 0x2b: yield return $"sw\t{_reg[rt]}, {nImm}({_reg[rs]})"; break;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `IEnumerable<string> code = ...` it means that it will enumerate one by one (every `yield`) when someone wants to use it, in the example `File.WriteLines` will enumerate it

Comment: @codequestion Yeah they are the file name your are reading, and the file name you want to write to

Comment: `GetCode(@"C:\sdfsdfsdfdsf\sdfsdf.txt")` ect